# plc structured text loop delay

Tags: plc, structured-text

I am trying to have a loop where it will start at 100 and drop until it hits to a point where the while condition no longer holds true.

I started with

```
While Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER <= OneHundred AND BatChargePercent < OneHundred DO
    State_Dis_Charge := false
    FOR PLC_SetLoopChargeValue:= 100 TO 0 By -1  DO
        ConvertoReal   := INT_TO_LREAL(PLC_SetLoopChargeValue);
        Divide         := ConvertoReal DIV(100);
        PLC_SetCharge  := Divide;         
        PLC_Charge     := 1500 * PLC_SetCharge; 
        RB_Charge      := PLC_Charge;
        Visual_RBPower := 1500 * PLC_SetCharge;    (*Charge *) 
    END_FOR;
```

The problem I believe I have with this is that it cycles too fast so the condition never gets out of the while loop because it takes a while for the system to update so I thought of adding a delay portion:

```
While Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER <= OneHundred AND BatChargePercent < OneHundred DO
    State_Dis_Charge := false;
    wait(IN:=not wait.Q , PT:=T#50ms);
    if Wait.Q Then 
        FOR PLC_SetLoopChargeValue:= 100 TO 0 By -1  DO
            ConvertoReal   := INT_TO_LREAL(PLC_SetLoopChargeValue);
            Divide         := ConvertoReal DIV(100);
            PLC_SetCharge  := Divide;         
            PLC_Charge     := 1500 * PLC_SetCharge; 
            RB_Charge      := PLC_Charge;
            Visual_RBPower := 1500 * PLC_SetCharge;    (*Charge *) 
        END_FOR; 
    END_IF;
END_WHILE;
```

How I think it should work is every 50ms 1 for loop should run. Currently nothing happens every 50ms.

Comment: Hi Tony! It was a little hard to understand the code as you haven't provided the full example. It would be necessary to have all the declarations of the software. But I can immediately see why it doesn't go out of the loop. You don't seem to change the variable Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER  nor the variable BatChargePercent. Whatever value they held when the WHILE-loop started is the value they will keep.

Comment: yes this is part of a larger code. Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER is a percentage that gets calculated based on meter readings which will determine if it goes in or out of the loop. In more detail as it runs the condition is met so it changes the charge rate by 1 percent each for loop cycle.  Problem is it cycles too fast so when for example it goes from 100% to 30% in less than a second the system does not react fast enough to the change so it will cycle back to 100% and drop again over and over. So i tried adding a delay and i it causes issues

Comment: `Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER`, `OneHundred` Or `BatChargePercent` have to be changed inside the loop otherwhise loop will never end.

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider that `WHILE` and `FOR` are executed synchronously. It means blocking. It means that interpreter do not execute next line, until previous line is finished.

1. This means that "running to fast" cannot apply here. It does not matter how fast it runs, the execution of the lines will be always in order.
2. The only thing I would change and loop not from 100 to 0 but vice versa from 0 to 100, because I am not sure this backward will work fine. And then all you have to change:

   ```
   ConvertoReal   := INT_TO_LREAL(100 - PLC_SetLoopChargeValue);
   ```
3. You do now show all code it is VERY HARD to judge but if `FOR` loom is complete it totally make no sense. You calculate some variables but you do not use them there. You know that you cannot use them outside of your `FOR` loop, right? Because outside of your `FOR` loop those variable will be always same value of last loop.
4. In your second example your `FOR` loop, although it might work, you should not use timer to run the loop inside the loop. Because loops are synchronous and times async.
5. As I understand you task you do not need `WHILE` at all. With this approach your program execution of other parts will be blocked until 100%. That might take a while as I can see. So you have to use `IF`.

   ```
   IF Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER <= OneHundred AND BatChargePercent < OneHundred DO
       // ....
   END_IF;
   ```

   The difference is significant. With `WHILE` it will block your program till `WHILE` finish and other parts will not be executed for this long, in the same PLC cycle `FOR` might be executed so many times.

   With `IF` if will run `FOR` one time per one PLC cycle and actualy doe snot change your logic.
6. If you would share your full code or at least parts where variables you have here are used so that the whole picture is visible, you might get a better help. Edit your post and I'll edit my comment.

Answer (score 0):

With this answer im only adressing your issue with the for loop not being executed every 50ms. 
The other answers why the while loop cant be exited are correct unless the variables `Solar_Power_House_W_Solar_PER` and `BatChargePercent` aren't changed in a parrellel thread.

I suggest `wait` is a TON function block. Please mind that names of FBs are case sensitive: `wait.Q` is possibly unequal `Wait.Q`. I think that is the main reason your for loop is not executed, because you check the output of another FB. Maybe check your declaration list for doubles with higher or lower cases.

Another possibility is, that your condition for the while loop isn't met at all and you didn't notice. In this case the for loop wouldn't be executed too of course.